# Creating marketing videos

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to create a marketing video with multiple images (png/jpg) after adding texts on every single image and of course with their duration. Therefor, I use several ffmpeg commands, because I am not able to do it with just one command.

How can I define a text and a duration for every image before adding it to the video?

### My example batch file:

## !/bin/bash

echo "[Start]"
ffmpeg \
    -i '01.jpg' \
    -vf drawtext="\text='Stack Overflow': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.9: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" \
    -codec:a copy \
    -y 'out-a.mp4'
ffmpeg \
    -i '02.jpg' \
    -vf drawtext="\text='Another Text': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.9: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" \
    -codec:a copy \
    -y 'out-b.mp4'
ffmpeg \
    -i '03.jpg' \
    -vf drawtext="\text='Hello World': fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.9: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2" \
    -codec:a copy \
    -y 'out-c.mp4'
ffmpeg \
    -i out-*.mp4 \
    -vf scale=768x420 \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -r 30 \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -y 'output.mp4'
echo "[End]"

Thanks to all
Cengiz

Comment: Sorry, the format is a little bit bad to read it.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1336844